# what will happen if the android app installation was interrupted forcefully?

Tags: android, device, android-instant-apps

I want to know if I interrupt the android app updating installation procedure (like turn off the device); will the app be corrupted? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No app wont be damaged.
Unless the app installation is completed you cannot use the application. If you interrupt the installation - installation will resume once you are back online.